# How to generate Documents on-fly using PHP for microsoft and openoffice together?

Tags: php, ms-office, openoffice.org

I want to generate doc (or odt) and xls document files using PHP, The problems is that both Microsoft office and open office should be able to open the files without warning, nicely and similar using any document reader.

Also there are images inside the documents that should be saved as embedded file, does anybody know any component, class or way that can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for excel files you can use this, http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/ it covers just about everything that you can do in microsoft excel and last time i used it worked really well. Also seems like it can do a few other formats.

you would need to find something similar for doc and odt files. best bet is to just do odt as that can be opened in office, not the other way round afaik.

as for a one solution fits all, doubt you will find it.

Answer (score 1):

[OpenTBS](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/opentbs.php) is a PHP tool that can read an modify the contents of any OpenDocument files (ODT, ODS, ODG, ODF, ODM, ODP, OTT, OTS, OTG, OTP). But also OpenXML files (DOCX, XLSX, PPTX).

No temporary files needed, no command lines, all in PHP.